# How to create a job and attach it to a new changelist in perforce CLI?

Tags: perforce

using p4 change, I can create a new changelist but it requires a 'form' to be filled.

Is there a way for me to create a job with a particular template, get that job number and attach it to a new changelist with a particular template?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately you have to use the forms, i.e. temp files, or cmdline I/O redirection.

The alternative is to use a P4 API (e.g. P4Perl, P4Python, etc.) which gives you a way to specify all the change's details (the ones you would fill into the form) as structured data.